# SVN - How to Export Just a Revision

Tags: linux, svn, apache, webdav

I have SVN setup on my local computer (Ubuntu) which I use for development and an SVN client running on a shared host box which I use a staging server, also my production server has the same setup.  When I do an export, the entire project is getting exported which is absurd for small version release.  I use the following command:

```
svn export -r 31 http://localhost.com/proj/trunk . --force --username myusername
```

And the entire project is exported once again.  So I try a different way:

```
svn export -r 'COMMITTED' http://localhost.com/proj/trunk . --force --username myusername
```

I then get this error:

```
svn: 'http://localhost.com/egr' is not a working copy
svn: Can't open file 'http://localhost.com/proj/.svn/entries': No such file or directory
```

I wonder if I am just not using the correct SVN export command or if there is something inherently wrong with my SVN setup (this is my first time configuring SVN).

dav_svn.conf:

```
  <Location /proj>
 DAV svn
 SVNPath /var/svn/proj/
 AuthType Basic
 AuthName "SVN Repo"
 AuthUserFile /etc/subversion/passwd
 <LimitExcept GET PROPFIND OPTIONS REPORT>
    Require valid-user
 </LimitExcept>
```

Ideas? Please advise.

Comment: svn export with `-rev` is used for exporting all files at that specific revision, not just the modified files as you want

Answer (score 14):

You can specify the folder/files that you want to export only, like

such as using wp svn

```
svn export -r 16873 http://core.svn.wordpress.org/branches/2.8/wp-admin/css
```

If just few files but located on different directories

```
mkdir {css,image}
svn export -r 16873 http://core.svn.wordpress.org/branches/2.8/wp-admin/css/install.css css/install.css
svn export -r 16873 http://core.svn.wordpress.org/branches/2.8/wp-admin/images/menu-arrows.gif images/menu-arrows.gif
```

Comment: I was going to ask systematical to clarify what it is he actually wants to do but I think you hit it on the head.  @systematical: I think you're just not realizing that the repository url goes deeper than the root.

Comment: I just want to "upload" my most recently committed files to my staging server.  So i thought by specifying a revision number it would just move over those files.  Or if I had multiple revisions I wanted to upload I could do something like -r 31:35.  Thats what I am attempting to accomplish.

Comment: do you mean download instead of upload?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `svn export` if you want to update the project, you should use `svn commit` that sends changes from your working copy to the repository.

I was wondering Why are you using the -r 31 option this stands for revisions and the amount of them which are 31. Probably the option you want to invoke is the -R option which stands for recursing the directories.

Comment: I think `-r 31` in this context means "at revision 31", so, in context, "get something from this repository path as it was at revision 31"